# python parse file and put in for loop

Tags: python, linux, for-loop

I want to parse `httpd_` from `chkconfig` output using python for loop or whatever the easy way.

```
[spatel@04 ~]$ /sbin/chkconfig --list| grep httpd_
httpd_A    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
httpd_B      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
httpd_C      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

I know how to do in `bash` but i want same thing in `python`.

```
[spatel@04 ~]$ for qw in `/sbin/chkconfig --list| grep httpd_ | awk '{print $1}'`
> do
> echo $qw
> done
httpd_A
httpd_B
httpd_C
```

How to do it in python? my python version is

```
[root@04 ~]# python -V
Python 2.4.3
```

Comment: Aside: your bash is somewhat convoluted. Try: `/sbin/chkconfig --list | awk '/^httpd_/ { print $1 }'`. `for` and `grep` and backticks are not required.

Comment: That is not an issue, i want same function in python...

Comment: Right -- that's why its a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Robᵩ that is so sweet. good to know we can use awk for extract string.. upvote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the line on whitespace using `.split()` and test if the first element starts with a string using `.startswith()`:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['chkconfig', '--list'])

for line in output.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('httpd_'):
        print line.split()[0]
```

For older python versions, use a `Popen()` call directly:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['chkconfig', '--list'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

for line in output:
    if line.startswith('httpd_'):
        print line.split()[0]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: My version is Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 16:39:10)

Comment: @Satish: ah, old, old python version then.

Comment: All latest Linux machines are having Python2.6 which does not have attribute check_output. `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'`.

Comment: We have very old system, which i can't upgrade them... legacy application :(

Comment: @kvivek: that returns the exit code, useless if you want to read it's stdout instead.